# Recover .frm files using Foremost, etc on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted my database without taking a backup. I tried Foremost, but it can only recover about 20 file types. I want to recover .frm, .myd, and .myi. What are some other ways to recover them?

I'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely try [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).

Although its name sounds like from a recovery tool just for image file formats, it is an extremely powerful file carver and supports [a lot of different file types](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec) (at least `frm` and `myi` are supported).

Photorec is part of the *testdisk* package on Ubuntu and other Debian-based linux distributions. You can easily install it with `apt-get install testdisk` as root.

Also be sure to try the [latest version](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) from the photorec website if the (probably older) version in the Ubuntu/Debian repositories gives no sufficient results.